# Résumé: Additional details can be provided (if required / on request)

Tags: meaning-in-context, politeness

I'm a freshman applying for internships. I previously had a detailed résumé with appropriate information regarding my projects and areas of expertise. However, I want to tailor it down and keep it as simple as possible so I removed a lot of details.

However, I don’t want the recruiters to think I  don’t possess sufficient skills so I would like to mention a small note at the end of my résumé.

Either of the following:

1. Further details on projects and subjects pursued during my Bachelor degree and Master degree can be provided if required.
2. Further details on projects and subjects pursued during my Bachelor degree and Master degree can be provided on request.

Which sentence would sound more polite to the recruiter?

Comment: "On request" is slightly nicer than "if required." However, IMO both options are a little wordy for a resume. In my own resume, I use this: References & Work History From Before 2004 Available On Request.

Comment: They're "Bachelor's" and "Master's". They're possessive. Also, "do not" is two words. "On request" is probably better, because it implies a non-adversarial relationship. "If required" makes you sound reluctant. Also, agree with @WilliamBloom .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've already detailed your degrees in the Education section of your resume, it seems a bit wordy to say

> during my Bachelor degree and Master degree

Instead you might just say, " during my education."

And I would say " ..provided *upon* request."

Answer (score 0):

If minimalism is the goal then use the context of your Masters/Bachelor's and attach a simple side-note:

> Details on request

Prefix with *Project* if that's not obvious.